# i want to send data from client side to server side when user disconnect from socket.io connection with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

i want to send data from client side to server side when user disconnect from socket.io connection with Nodejs`your text i have try to make another one event and called under disconnect event which is not possible because connection is closed.`

Comment: This is likely not a good architecture because many of the reasons that a socket.io connection has gone away means that the whole page context has gone away.  If there's some info the server needs from the client, then perhaps you should  just keep that info up-to-date by regularly s ending it from the client to the server (over the socket.io connection) so that when the client disconnects, the server already has the info it needs.  For further ideas, we would have to know more about what the data is, how often it changes and why the server needs the "last" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client side, you can use

```
window.addEventListener('unload',()=>{
//Emit websocket/socket.io event here
})
```

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that you can successfully send data over socket.io in the `unload` event.

Comment: You should try this out with socket.io. Works fine with websocket.

Comment: What about the other ways that a socket.io connection is lost like the phone just went out of coverage or the computer just went to sleep or the network went down.  The OP's architecture here is just flawed because there's lots of different ways a connection can go down and most of them do not have the ability to send more data.

Answer (score 0):

When a user disconnects from a Socket.IO connection, you can send data from the client-side to the server-side by emitting an event just before the disconnection event occurs. The key is to send the data before the connection is fully closed. Here's how you can achieve this:

// Emit an event with data just before disconnecting

```
socket.emit('disconnecting', { someData: 'This is some data' });
```

// Disconnect from the server

```
socket.disconnect();
```

Comment: but in when user diconnected i need to perform some operation like store data in database when user disconnetd

Comment: You can develop a custom API that will be called from the frontend after the socket connection is closed, allowing you to perform actions and save data in the database.